# cannot submit first form because of required fields in second form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, required

**Help** 
I want to find way that how to submit first form which is placed in the first tab without concerning second tab required fields.
Now when I press submit button nothing happen. this is because, is waiting for second form which is in second tab. how Can I separate these tabs?

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-3 ">
  <br>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#first">First Tab</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#second">Second Tab</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="row  tab-pane fade in active" id="first">
    <br>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <select class=" btn-block form-control" name="type1" required >
          <option value="a">AAAA</option>
          <option value="b">BBBB</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <input type="number" name="type2" class=" btn-block form-control" step="25" min="200" required  >
        <br>
        <input type="number" name="type3" class=" btn-block form-control" min="0" required >
        <br>
        <button type="Submit" class="text-center btn-block btn-warning form-control"
          name="search1">Search Now</button>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row  tab-pane fade" id="second">
       <br>
       <div class="col-lg-12">
         <select class=" btn-block form-control" name="type4" required >
          <option value="c">CCCC</option>
          <option value="d">DDDD</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <input type="number" name="type5" class=" btn-block form-control" step="25" min="200" required  >
        <br>
        <input type="number" name="type6" class=" btn-block form-control" min="0" required >
        <br>
        <button type="Submit" class="text-center btn-block btn-warning form-control"
          name="search2">Search Now</button>
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are the `<form>` tags?